# Delete an Archive Folder in MS Outlook

Tags: outlook

I want to remove / delete an Archive folder in MS Outlook 
Version:  MS Office Professional Plus 2016.

I have tried closing the archive and it did close and disappear only to re-appear the next time I opened outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File > Account Settings > Account Settings... > Data Files > Open file location(Of the archive folder you want to delete) > right click the .pst file > delete.